# Jews time in exile

Tags: contradiction, ezekiel, jeremiah

Jeremiah prophesied 70 years of Babylonian captivity, which began 606 BC and ended in 536 BC. On the other hand, Ezekiel, while 30 years into this captivity (Eze 1:1), prophesied 390 and 40 years respectively, of exile and foreign domination of both Ephraim and Judah, Eze 4:4-9. How does this tie up?

Comment: Following the reign of Solomon, the Jews were divided into two kingdoms, Judah and Israel. The two regions were not conquered at the same time by the Babylonians (consult the final chapters of 2 Kings and 2 Chronicles for more detailed information on this topic).

Comment: Please quote the specific passages you're referring to here.

Answer (score 0):

There are three separate questions here so I will take them one at a time.  Spoiler alert: There is not enough data to properly answer any of them.  However let me very briefly review the little data we have.

**Thirtieth Year (Eze 1:1)**

Given it was the fifth year of the reign of King Jehoiachin (Eze 1:2, 2 Kings 24:6-15) who was taken captive in 597 BC, makes this date either 592 BC.  The first year using Ezekiel's dating system would be the 18th year of King Josiah when the Book of the Law was found (2 Kings 22:3-8) - a date that began a period of significant reform in Judah.  Therefore, "thirtieth year" cannot refer to the thirtieth year of Judah's captivity but must be either:

- The thirtieth year of Ezekiel himself corresponding to the age when priests began to serve and thus Ezekiel was born in the same year as when the book of the law was found, or,
- Ezekiel simply uses this significant reform as in Josiah's 18th year as a prominent event from which to date his prophecies.

I find the first possibility more probable.

**390 Days/Years**

As stated above, Ezekiel received this vision about 592 BC.  The northern kingdom of Israel separated from Judah at the conclusion of Solomon's reign about 931 BC and wend into Assyrian captivity in 722 BC.  This means that the northern kingdom only existed for a little more that 200 years.  At the time of Ezekiel's vision back to its founding was less than 340 years.  That is, we do not know how this time period was calculated or understood by Ezekiel.  Even if the LXX reading of 150 days/years is adopted, no such time period is apparent.

**40 Days/Years**

There is an almost identical problem with the 40 years of Judah's rebellion.  Judah had witnessed a series of kings that were various loyal and rebellious to God.  No final solution to this has been proposed.